# Get 'layers' name form GeoServer link and assign it as a variable

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, layers

Using Leaflet and GeoServer.

Basically, I want to be able to add a new layer with a different bounding box that is user defined by selecting an area on the map. I want it to work with all layers available... so if I could just get the 'layers' name and update it when a new overlay is turned on/off

User turns on a tileLayer with many points on the map. User selects an area on the map with points. The selection area is converted to new bounding box dimensions. A new layer of the same map is added but with with the new bounding box.

I have everything except how to get the name of the current tile layer so that I can make the GeoServer call. It would look like this:

var currentLayerName;

```
  function addGeoServerLayer(){
       geoServerLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: **currentLayerName**, **<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  I NEED THIS**
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: false,
           CQL_FILTER : 'BBOX(geom, ' + boundingBox + ')'
        }).addTo(layersGroup);

    }
```

I want to be able to pull the 'layers' field from this list of tileLayers in my project (leaflet project). this way, after the user selects an area, I can make a geoserver and return the same map with new bounding box values and I can do it no matter what layer is selected.

```
        var layer1 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: 'test:layer1',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true
        });

        var layer2 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: 'test:layer2',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
        });

        var layer3 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: 'test:layer3',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true
        });

        var layer4 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: 'test:layer4',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true      
        });            

        var layer5 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: 'test:layer5',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true
        });

        var layer6 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://12.235.22.99:8080/geoserver/ows?", {
            layers: 'test:layer6',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone needing this info.... After writing a convoluted function that hacks a geoserver url apart to get the layer name, I found out you can just use the following:

```
    map.on('overlayadd', function(e){
        var activeOverlay = e.layer.options.layers;
    });
```

So simple.

Comment: To call the remove event    map.on('overlayremove', function (e) {
                            debugger;
                            var activeOverlay = e.layer.options.layers;
                        });

Answer (score 0):

The layers available at your WMS endpoint depend on the configuration of your WMS server.

Either check your GeoServer configuration, or check the `getCapabilities` document of your WMS endpoint. Connecting to your WMS endpoint with a graphical client (e.g. qgis) will request the `getCapabilities` document and display the available layer names.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I don't really need a list of layer names, I need a way call the specific layer name... something like:        "layers: layer.getName()" ... is there any method that I can pull that information and updated it depending on what tileLayer is active?

Comment: Pull that information **from where**?

Comment: Sorry.. from my Leafletjs  project file. You can turn tileLayers on/off. Those tileLayers are pulled form GeoServer. I would like to grab the "layers" name from whichever tileLayer is currently active (which box is checked.). That way, if I turn on layer1, var getCurrentName = <active layer name of layer 1> or whatever. Then, if I turn off 1 and turn on layer2, var getCurrentName = <active layer name of layer2>. I apologize for being confusing.

Comment: How many tilelayers do you have? How are you instantiating them? Please edit your original question to reflect this.